# Localhost OR loopback naming

Tags: network-programming

During development of an IpAddress library's part, I'm confronted to a minor dilema.
How to name my function testing the address to be a LocalHost / Loopback.
What is the difference between this 2 designations?

In other libs , they make this choices:

> Boost.asio -> is_loopback
>
> Qt -> isLoopback
>
> wxWidget -> IsLocalHost

Why do they call `isLoopback` a test like `address == "::1"` ??

ANSWER:
"localhost" is usually an alias for the "loopback" interface. They can and are often used interchangeably.

Subquestion: Is it the same definition between IPv4 and IPv6?

Comment: "localhost" is usually an alias for the "loopback" interface. They can and are often used interchangeably.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you! I'll rewrite that in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous answer is not entirely correct.

Loopback +interface+ may have configured multiple IP addresses, not only from localhost network. It is a common practice to put non-local address on loopback interface in e.g. dynamic routing, where you don't want to lose routes to router's IP in case any interface goes down.

On the other hand, loopback IPv4 +network+ is defined by [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/ipv4-address-space.xhtml) as 127.0.0.0/8. Surprisingly, for IPv6 [they reserved](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-address-space/ipv6-address-space.xml) only ::1/128 address.

To answer your question: if you want to check only addresses, I'd pick isLocalhost(). And to be a bit zealous, I'd check there for the whole network - I happened to see 127.0.0.2 a few times...